# How to make a left side curve as if it were a U without absolute position?

Tags: ios, react-native, android-styles

I want to make the curve that appears in the image, the one that has the gray color brackground that makes like a U. Without an absolute position for me, then I can use a button above that same background

[image]

Comment: If you make something `position:absolute` and then set the `zIndex:99` it will overlay the thing below it.

Comment: yes, but how can i make that curve?

Comment: You can use `react-native-svg` (https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg)

Comment: You can make a bunch cool loking shapes with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do to get that red curve with no imports is to make a circle within the view and then do `overflow:'hidden'` in the parent view. So the circle doesn't overflow out of it. Next you make use of `transform` and `translate` to move it in the x and y direction to the left corner.

Full example here (https://snack.expo.dev/@heytony01/anxious-kiwi)

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"}}>
        <View style={{width:"90%",height:"15%",backgroundColor:"gray",borderRadius:"3%",flexDirection:"row",
        // Need this so the child view doesn't overflow it
        overflow:"hidden",}}>
            <View style={{
              // Makes a giant circle
              width:"100%",
              height:"200%",
              borderRadius:"100%",
              backgroundColor:"red", 
              // Adds a border with a color white
              borderColor:"white",
              borderWidth:2,
              // Move the cirlce to the left side
              transform:[
                {
                  translateX:-150
                },
                {
                  translateY:-50
                }
              ]
            }}>
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```